# React Native performance of Accelerometer, Gyroscope, Sound Recording

Tags: react-native

I need to develop an app that collects data from GPS, Accelerometer, takes a few pictures a day and records sound. All the data needs to be processed and sent to a server. I am new to iOS development and thinking **if it's a good idea to use React-Native for this kind of application?** And if using React-Native is **less time consuming then Swift?**

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am making something similar, and the answer to your question is: It depends.

Is the app only for iOS? If yes, learn Swift.

Is your app running in the background? If yes, learn Swift or something else.

Are you familiar with Javascript? If no, learn Swift.

The reason is React Native only works when your app is running in foreground. If you need background tasks, such as collecting GPS coordinates when the app is minimized, you will need to roll your own native codes. At that case, you will need to learn Objective-C/Swift AND Java if you use RN.